# About an algebraic construction of a sheaf of formal microdifferential operators

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, d-modules

While reading these [notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/grad_2009/Ginzburg.pdf) by Victor Ginzburg on $D$-modules I found a certain construction of Microlocailzation in the algebraic setting which unfortunately doesn't seem to be elaborated on a lot in there. Let me describe the construction:

Let $A$ be an almost commutative algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$ (positively filtered whose associated graded is of finite type). Denote by $\sigma: A \to grA$ the multiplicative map sending an element to its corresponding "symbol" in the associated graded.

The following proposition is proved about ore localizations in this context:

> **Proposition:** Let $\tilde{S} \subset grA$ be a multiplicatively closed subset. Then $S = \{a \in A : \sigma(a) \in \tilde{S} \}$ satisfies ore conditions. Meaning there exists a noncommutative localization $S^{-1}A$.

He then introduces a $\mathbb{Z}$-filtration on $S^{-1}A$ naturally as follows:

$$(S^{-1}A)_n = \{s^{-1}a \in S^{-1}A : deg\sigma(a)-deg\sigma(s)=n  \}$$

> **Definition:** The completion of $S^{-1}A$ w.r.t. the filtration defined above is called **formal microlocalization** of $A$ at $S$ and denoted $A_S$.

Further arguments show $U \to A_U$ defines a sheaf of algebras on the affine scheme $Spec(grA)$ And that for any finitely generated $A$-module the assignment $U \to M_U := A_U \otimes_A M$ defines a sheaf of modules over it.

It seems to me that this construction can be generalized to give microlocalization of $\mathcal{D}_X$ for general smooth varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Let's denote by $\mathcal{E}_X$ the sheaf obtained from the procedure above applied to $\mathcal{D}_X$.

It therefore raises the questions:

> 1. How does the sheaf $\mathcal{E}_X$ relate to **Sato's sheaf of formal microdifferential operators**?  (on the analytic cotanget bundle of $X$ of course).
> 2. **Can $\mathcal{E}_X$ be described explicitly** (generators and relations) in simple examples? ($Spec \mathbb{C}[[x]], Spec \mathbb{C}[x], \mathbb{A}^n$).

And finally:

> Is this algebraic side of microlocalization developed anywhere in the literature? If so where?

Comment: Based on the intro to http://www.ams.org/tran/1989-316-02/S0002-9947-1989-0958890-X/S0002-9947-1989-0958890-X.pdf, it seems like you want to look at T. Springer’s “Micro-localization algébrique”

Comment: You may also find https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=87rwCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR6&ots=tTTFNHpmcK&dq=zariskian%20filtered%20rings&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=zariskian%20filtered%20rings&f=false to be of some interest re your final question.